# Prevent triggering of parent group (group events bubble up)

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

If you add an eventhandler to a group (not an element like rectangle) and this group also contains a group with an eventhandler and you trigger an event on the child group (click), it will also trigger the parents eventhandler. 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7k5sj/1/)
How can you prevent that the parent is triggered? If you add the handlers to the rectangles, the event doesn't bubble up.

```
    var svgElement=document.getElementById("mainSvgId");
    var s = Snap(svgElement);
    s.attr({height: 300, width: 300});

    var parentGroup=s.g().attr({id: "parent"});
    var rect1 = s.rect(0, 0, 200, 200).attr({fill: "#bada55"});
    parentGroup.add(rect1);
    parentGroup.click(function(){
        console.log("id parent: " + this.node.id);
    })

    var childGroup=s.g().attr({id: "child"});
    var rect2 = s.rect(100, 100, 30, 30).attr({fill: "#ff0055"});
    childGroup.add(rect2);
    parentGroup.add(childGroup);
    childGroup.click(function(){
        console.log("id child: " + this.node.id);
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to change last 4 lines to prevent the event from propagating on it's parents:

```
    childGroup.click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation()
        console.log("id child: " + this.node.id);
    })
```

[updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7k5sj/2/)