# Event Bubbling in Nested SVGs

Tags: snap.svg

When I nest SVGs with snap.svg and add click handlers to them using the snap.svg Element.click() function, I am unable to stop the click on an inner element from bubbling and also triggering the click handler of the parent(s).  The obvious answer, stopPropogation, is not working, and I'm guessing that's because snap.svg's click() function is somehow hijacking it.

The question, and what looks like a good answer, [has been asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308701/prevent-triggering-of-parent-group-group-events-bubble-up), but the solution doesn't work in the answer's Fiddle and it doesn't for me either.

I found a temporary workaround, which is to change the parent Element.click() to Element.dblclick(), but I really would like to be able to use Element.click() for all my SVGs.  Any thoughts?

**UPDATE AFTER RESPONSES FROM NICHOLAS KYRIAKIDES AND IAN**

Thank you for the sanity check, as it helped solve the issue.  The Fiddle still does not work for me in Chrome and Firefox, but after Ian's comment I tried the code from the Fiddle locally as-is and it did indeed work.  So that led me to Nicholas' response, and I tried a few different ways of using stopPropogation and got it working.  My particular case involved reassigning a click on click, which was causing problems.  Here's the new (working) abbreviated code of the child element click handler in case it might help someone:

```
childElement.click(function(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    // initial click handling code goes here

    // unbind the current click handler for the element
    element.unclick();

    // set the new click handler
    element.click(function(e) {

        e.stopPropagation();

        // new click handling code goes here

    });
});
```

Thanks for straightening me out.

Comment: you are most likely using `e.stopPropagation` wrong. Can you post some code?

Comment: Works fine for me in the solution fiddle